# When filtering ng-options, how do I de-select all filtered out options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multi-select of campaigns, when I select a new client, I would like the campaigns to be scoped to the selected clients.

The filter works as expected, however, the `ng-model` of `campaigns` could contain a campaign that was hidden with the filter.

I would like all filtered out campaign options be deselected when they are no longer in the select.

Here is my filter:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .filter('campaignFilter', function(){
    return function(options, client_ids, $scope) {
      if (client_ids == null) {
        return options;
      } else {
        filtered = [];

        angular.forEach(options, function(option){
          if (client_ids.indexOf(option.client_id) > -1) {
            filtered.push(option);
          } else {
            idx = $scope.filter["campaign.id"].indexOf(option.client_id);
            if idx > -1 {
              $scope.filter["campaign.id"].splice(idx, 1);
            };
          };
        });

        return filtered;
      }
    }
  });
```

**Update:**

I have a filter object on $scope that I need to update when filtering campaigns.

```
$scope.filter["campaign.id"] = [1,2,3]
```

When a client is selected, I want to remove all campaign ids from `$scope.filter["campaign.id"]` that don't belong to that client.

When I pass in the scope to the filter, `$scope.filter` is null. So how can I have access to a scope model?

Comment: what does `deselected` mean? All you've shown is a filter

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that the ng-model is updated by removing all selected options that were hidden with the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you want to be able to get an array of all those campaigns that exist after the non-applicable ones have been filtered out?

If so, you could declare you campaign select like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCampaign" ng-options="campaign.name for campaign in filteredCampaigns = (campaigns | campaignFilter: clientIds)"></select>
```

Then you have the filtered array aviable in the scope property `filteredCampaigns`.

Here is an attempt to demonstrate this in action. I made some assumptions about how you are trying to do this, since you didn't mention your controller or view code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.filter = {
    'campaign.id': []
  } 

  $scope.campaigns = [{
    client_id: 1,
    id: 1,
    name: 'campaign 1'
  }, {
    client_id: 1,
    id: 2,
    name: 'campaign 2'
  }, {
    client_id: 1,
    id: 3,
    name: 'campaign 3'
  }, {
    client_id: 2,
    id: 4,
    name: 'campaign 4'
  }, {
    client_id: 2,
    id: 5,
    name: 'campaign 5'
  }, {
    client_id: 3,
    id: 6,
    name: 'campaign 6'
  }, ];
  
  
$scope.clientIds = [1];

$scope.$watch('filteredCampaigns', function(val) {
     $scope.filter['campaign.id'] = val.map(function(item) { return item.id });
  });
})


.filter('campaignFilter', function() {
  return function(options, client_ids) {
    if (client_ids == null) {
      return options;
    } else {
      filtered = [];

      angular.forEach(options, function(option) {
        if (client_ids.indexOf(option.client_id) > -1) {
          filtered.push(option);
        };
      });

      return filtered;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-app="app">
    <label>
      Campaign
      <select ng-model="selectedCampaign" ng-options="campaign.name for campaign in filteredCampaigns = (campaigns | campaignFilter: clientIds)"></select>
  </label>
  <br><br>
  Client id: <input ng-model="clientIds" size="2" >
  
  <p><pre>filter['campaign.id']: {{ filter['campaign.id']}}</pre></p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify more. I think I need to edit a scope object inside of my filter. Is that possible? I have tried to pass in the scope to the filter, which results in a dependency error.

Comment: Ok, I'm kind of getting it. It would make things a *lot* easier if you could also post the controller and view code (or at least the relevant portions)

Comment: Ok I edited my answer in light of the additional info you provided.  When you change the value of the "Client  id" input, you'll see the `$scope.filter['campaign.id']` array update to include only the filtered campaigns. I did not need to change your filter code to do this - it's all done in the controller & view.